# thinking sphinx association in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

i have this:

## User model

```
define_index do
    indexes username
    indexes [contact.last_name,contact.first_name] ,:sortable => true,:as=>:user_full_name
     #no results        
    indexes profiles.working_experiences.job_title,:as=>:user_job_title
end
```

I never get results for job_title...
What i missing here?

Comment: What's the search query you're using that's not getting the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your associations through the models

2) Make sure you reference :user_job_title in the search command, not job_title as you are aliasing it